# WWW rate limit via Skyhigh (formerly McAfee?) Web Gateway (SaaS web gateway)

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I've been getting intermittent HTTP 429 (Too Many Requests) responses from https://stackoverflow.com today, and I think I've tracked it down to our company network routing outbound web traffic through Skyhigh "Secure Web Gateway", which is basically a SaaS corporate web proxy.

The address reported in the HTTP 429 response is 161.69.71.25, which matches part of their published PoP IP range:

From https://success.myshn.net/Skyhigh_Secure_Web_Gateway_(Cloud)/Secure_Web_Gateway_Concepts/IP_Addresses_and_Ranges:

> ###### PoPs per Region
>
> | Region | Physical Location | IP address/range | Inbound | Outbound | Publish Date |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Europe | England | **161.69.71.0/24** | X | X | May 31, 2022 |

I'm currently working with our SecOps team to get an exception added to our config to bypass the Secure Web Gateway for SO, but in the meantime I only have intermittent access to the site depending on how much other external customers of the SaaS product (who affinitise to the same PoP) have been hitting it :-(.

The answer might just be "don't use a large-scale shared-tenancy SaaS web proxy then", but I figured I should flag it up in case the rate limit has been changed recently and is causing other people similar issues...

Comment: I've heard a bunch of people mention intermittently that they've gotten too many requests errors. It *might* not be the large scale SAAS proxy .

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - good to know.. Although it's possible they might be on the same (or similar) service as well, I guess :-).